# Lag computation in Time Series with missing value in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series like. I want to compute lag N only if the date-time is continuous and skip computing lag when I encounter missing data. I don't want to  compute lag when previous entry is at more than N hours interval in R

```
                   t         val
  2005-01-17 17:30:00       14.3
  2005-01-17 18:30:00       14.0
  2005-01-17 19:30:00       14.3
  2005-01-17 22:30:00       14.9
  2005-01-17 23:30:00       14.2
  2005-01-18 00:30:00       14.1
```

There are missing entry for dates `2005-01-17 20:30:00`  `2005-01-17 21:30:00`. I want to compute lag N only if the date-time is continuous and skip computing lag when I encounter missing data.

Expected Output Result

```
                   t         val   val_lag   val_lag2
  2005-01-17 17:30:00       14.3        NA         NA
  2005-01-17 18:30:00       14.0      14.3         NA
  2005-01-17 19:30:00       14.3      14.0       14.3
  2005-01-17 22:30:00       14.9        NA         NA
  2005-01-17 23:30:00       14.2      14.9         NA
  2005-01-18 00:30:00       14.1      14.2       14.9
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `24:30:00`.  shouldn't that `2005-01-18 00:30:00`

Comment: ^ that ^... and also day should change

Comment: Thanks to point it out. It is human error while forming this sample :)

Answer (score 2):

We could create a grouping variable by taking the `diff` of the 't' column and then get the `lag` of 'val'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(t)!=1))) %>% 
   mutate(val_lag = lag(val)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   select(-grp)
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped partially. How do I compute lag of "n" instead of 1 with same strategy?

Comment: @Mansoor I don't understand the partially.  It is giving the expected output as in your post

Comment: I am trying to compute lag N.

Comment: @Mansoor Can you update your post with the expected about N.